# Java3d Mac OSX Installation Instruction for a Newbie

Tags: java, macos, installation, java-3d

I am trying to use java3d on my mac osx and i cant find installation instructions anywhere!
if anyone knows how to do this or if there are any alternatives to java3d (i know jmonkeyengine is one) please let me know!

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

1. On Java 3D's download page you will find 'j3d-1_5_2-macosx.zip'. The installation process is described in 'README-unzip.html' : http://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html
2. Check if Apple's out-dated Java 3D version 1.3 is installed in System/Library/Java/Extensions/ on your Mac. Remove all Java 3D 1.3 related files (jar, jnilib), they are useless.

August, InteractiveMesh

Comment: Sorry for putting a question here - InteractiveMesh, did you manage to get Java3D working with JDK7 on OSX (Lion)?

Answer (score 1):

well there is JOGL (java opengl), java3d and jme (JMonkey Engine). Jogl is the most basic in the sense it is like writing openGL but in java so you can access the c commands.

JMonkeyEngine use: http://code.google.com/p/jmonkeyengine/downloads/list and select the mac version for more info look here: http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/Documentation. Btw downloading from the above will be using their sdk, but it is worth a try unless you really want to program in netbeans/eclipse. Here is some video of jME 3 http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=iv&v=cTErYjsJ_Yk&annotation_id=annotation_195125, including their editor.

Btw, a year or two ago when I was interested in Java 3d coding I found that Java3D was left by the waist side, not sure if it has been resurrected or not. I did see mention it was, but I am not too sure, you should research that if you will seriously develop code.

Jogl was dead but the site http://jogamp.org/ seems to have their own brew and maybe updating the old one, not too sure, but they have quite a few low level coding platforms if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Java 3D and several examples are installed in `/Developer/Examples/Java/Java3D/` as part of Apple's [*Developer Tools*](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/).